# What happens when you run out of time in Boss Rush?

Tags: rabi-ribi

Every boss in boss rush has a timer. When the time runs out the backdrop colors invert and the music goes slowly, but does something actually happen to the fight? Is there some sort of buff or debuff that activates then?

Answer (score 1):

- You gain a buff that lets you deal 2× damage.
- The boss gains a buff that lets her deal 4× damage.

(dunno what else happens)